# How can I get list of all items with query received?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am making a Django project in which I have User List which contains various Items. Each Item has its attribute like name, quantity and date.

This is my model of items:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('BOUGHT', 'BOUGHT'),
        ('NOT AVAILABLE', 'NOT AVAILABLE'),
        ('PENDING', 'PENDING'),
    )
    userlist = models.ForeignKey(userList, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    item_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    item_status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

This is my views.py:

```
def listView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        fd = None
        user_id = request.user.id
        userlist, created = userList.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)
        items = userlist.item_set.all()
        if request.body:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            fd=data['date']
    else:
        items = None

    context = {'items': items}
    return render(request, 'list_manager/index.html', context)
```

Here, fd is the query 'date' received from body.
By default, items contains all the items present in the list.
Now I just want the list of objects which have item.date==fd, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`request.POST`**[Django-Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) instead of using json module to load the request body. If `request.POST.get("date")` is not a datetime object but a string then you'd need to parse it to datetime object using **[`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)**.

```
def listView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        fd = None
        user_id = request.user.id
        userlist, created = userList.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user_id)
        items = userlist.item_set.filter(date=request.POST.get("date"))
    else:
        items = None

    context = {"items": items}
    return render(request, "list_manager/index.html", context)
```

Comment: I was successfully able to query, but the page doesn't show the required output, because request.method remains as POST. How can I change that?

Comment: To get the query parameter for filtering from HTML form, I am using POST method

Comment: this was not the scope of this question. maybe you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data by using this code:

```
items = userlist.item_set.filter(date=request.POST.get("date"))
```